# Entity framework doesn't add all tables visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Maybe its better to start with some info. I'am using Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft SQL server 2012 Express. So I have relationship between some tables like the standard one in simple membership between `UserProfile` `webpages_Roles` and `webpages_UsersInRoles` so `UsersInRoles` is just linking table .

but when I import them with entity framework Add / New Item / ADO.NET Entity Data Model then  i select my Database then select all tables and when i import them the linking table is not there... I can see it in associations

I got only these two..... When I try to add them separately The connection between these tables is not created.... 
All of these tables are standard membership tables with little improvements by my site in UserProfile.... but when i create my own table with same relationship it's not imported also. Please help.

When i create new User and a new Role I want to be able manually to add something in this table. Actually my biggest problem is that i have my own tables with the same relationship and I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but I'll try to answer anyway.

It looks like you are dealing with membership tables.  Below is an example that will add Roles and Users.  *WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection* method will create table if it doesn't exist.

```
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                        "DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", 
                        "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Agent"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Agent");
        }

        AddUser("admin", "Admin", "123");
        AddUser("agent", "Agent", "123");
    }
```

If you use Code First you can put this code in your Seed method so it will be created during a migration.

Once again I'm not sure if I answered your question.

Comment: These deals with my problem with membership tables... But when i want to add something in my custom table is impossible... Ok i'll try to explain it again I have 3 tables. Products , Check And ProductsInCheck so I want to be able to modify ProductsInCheck table which contains two columns ProductId and CheckId which are the Id of a product and the id of a check. So when doing this i'm able to put multiple products in one check for example in check 3 they are product 4,5,6,7 and my table will look like this 
3 4
3 5
3 6
3 7
But the entity framework doesn't import ProductInCheck table